# XSD unique: why does field/@xpath="." not work?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have a problem while validating some unique-constrains in XML using XSD. (I am validating with XMLlint) I have the following structure:

```
<xsd:element name="elem" type="elemType" >
      <xsd:unique name="uniqueJob">
        <xsd:selector xpath=".//jobs/job"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="."/>
    </xsd:unique>
</xsd:element>
```

Where jobs has a complex type deeply nested in the `<elem>` (I am using `<jobs>` more then once, thats why I defined the constraint in the root-elem) :

```
       <xsd:complexType name="jobType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="job" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="3" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
```

My problem now is the following: if I have something like

```
            <jobs>
                <job>Programmer</job>
                <job>Scientist</job>
            </jobs>
```

it does somehow don't validate. I Get the following error from XMLlint:
`Element 'job': The XPath './/jobs/job' of a field of unique identity-constraint 'uniqueJob' does evaluate to a node of non-simple type.`
but 'job' is a simple type. What I am missing here?
Thanks in Advance!

PS: I want to achieve that in each `<jobs>` tag each job is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change**

```
    <xsd:selector xpath=".//jobs/job"/>
    <xsd:field xpath="."/>
```

**to**

```
    <xsd:selector xpath=".//jobs"/>
    <xsd:field xpath="job"/>
```

**Explanation**

- The former requires that `job` elements be unique within the scope of itself – always true anyway.
- The latter requires that `job` elements be unique within the scope of their parent `jobs` elements – likely your actual intention.

**See also**

- [How to use xsd:unique?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38963495/290085)
- [Where to place xs:unique constraint in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29003329/290085)
- [Unique element in XSD is not enforced](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38468406/290085)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, helped me out indeed. Can you explain me the difference? I looked out for it,  but could not find a exact answer where the semantic difference is between this to expressions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're welcome.  Answer updated to explain the difference.